# Orient Object along Normal

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wan't to orientate my cylinders along the blue arrows. I am thinking that normals are the solution but since I am new to Geonodes in Blender I dont know how. Can you help me?

[image: Thats what I want to do]
[image: Thats what I tryed so far]

Comment: Just plug the node `Normal` into the *Vector* input of the node `Align Euler to Vector` and try with the axes... By the way, this question has been asked many times in different variants, so your question will probably be marked as a duplicate:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D+align+normals

Comment: ...I now wanted to take a closer look at your question and answer it, or search for a suitable duplicate. However, I do not quite understand this unfortunately. Please be so kind and edit your question to make it a bit clearer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, due to the structure of your *Geometry Nodes*, it is not entirely clear to me what exactly your goal is, so I'll try to provide an answer here based on a guess that might help you.

There are a lot of questions/answers that deal exactly with this topic, but in principle require the understanding of the node `Align Euler to Vector`.

Hence a try:

I assume you want to instantiate cylinders circularly on multiple planes.

1. Create a cylinder first.
2. Move it by half of its height on the *Z-axis*. Thus its rotation center is around the lower end.
3. Then instantiate it along the points of a circle.
4. Use the input node `Normal` on the input *Vector* of the node `Align Euler to Vector` to create a *Rotation* for the objects to be instantiated. Simply put, this node uses the normals of the points, and in this case aligns the *Z-axis* of the object to be instantiated along them.
5. Then instantiate this geometry again along the points of a line.

[image]

Maybe this answer will help you a bit. I just didn't want to leave the question unanswered.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>